# problem with tomcat server and a jersey api

Tags: jersey

After I prepared the tomcat server (v 7) and the a test project of jersey(v 2.16)
I am facing this problem

what can i do to fix this problem

Knowing that I haven't touched anything yet, the project is just beginning

```
    talina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)enter image description here
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```